# How do I insert a script tag in to the top/beginning of head tag using BHO?

Tags: c#, bho

I am using this code in c# for inject js into html page.this is working fine.

```
IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)document.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);

IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject3 = (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
scriptObject3.type = @"text/javascript";
scriptObject3.text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\all.js");
((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject3);
```

but i want to be this as first element in head tag.

```
<head>
//INSERT SCRIPT HERE
 <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="omni-controls.js"></script></head>
```

how this could be done in c#.

Comment: you can use ClientScript as property of page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("youScriptName"))
{
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "youScriptName", 
     @"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""yourpath/script.js""></script>");
}
```

You should do it in the `Page_Load`

Answer (score 0):

Get the first child of HEAD and use it as second parameter of the Element's method *insertBefore*.

Comment: Oddly enough, in *some* cases this will return S_OK and a NULL first child. Win 7 and IE 11 32 bit, Win XP and IE 8 working correctly though. And yes, this fails on document_complete event, and not for all cases.